# What is the dark stuff inside a green bell pepper?

Tags: chili-peppers, bell-peppers

My wife has been cutting up some green bell peppers and on the seeds is some dark stuff. The outside was firm and normal looking.

Comment: If its hairy it probably is some kind of mold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it was gassed to stay bright green and firm but the seeds are showing how old it actually is. The pith (the whitish veins on the sides) is also firm on a fresh pepper, if its limp probably due to age.

Comment: Would organic peppers be gassed?

Comment: Also, is it safe to eat?

Comment: @dan typically organic standards don't include preservation in the certification, it involves [other criteria like separation from non-organics, avoidance of certain  pesticides / fertilizers and unchemical farmland](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_certification)

Comment: Typically pith and seeds should be discarded anyway, but old veggies are not the best but are not necessarily bad or rotten unless they are rotting